# PHPStorm / WebStorm - httpd.conf File in Built-in Web Server?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I use the built-in web server in PHPStorm.  I would like to test server rewrites locally on this web server.  Is the PHPStorm web server powered by Apache?  If yes, where is the httpd.conf file located?

Comment: Use a Virtual machine for development (e.g. https://www.virtualbox.org/). Or if you're on linux, use https://www.docker.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the PHPStorm web server powered by Apache?

No -- it's very simple custom web server (Java based (as whole IDE) AFAIK).

---

**In any case:** the built-in server supports some **basic** .htaccess instructions (not many of them, AFAIK) .. but mod_rewrite instructions are not one of them.